# Error 1005 (HY000) MySQL Error

Tags: mysql

I have this code:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS courses;

USE 'courses'

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS teachers(
     id INT(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     addr VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     phone INT NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lessons(
     id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
     room TINYINT NOT NULL,
     length INT NOT NULL,
     lesson_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
     teacher INT NOT NULL,
     course INT NOT NULL,
     FOREIGN KEY(teacher) REFERENCES teachers(id),
     FOREIGN KEY(course) REFERENCES courses(id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS courses(
      id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
      title VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
      length INT NOT NULL,
      description TEXT DEFAULT '',
      previous INT NOT NULL,
     FOREIGN KEY(previous) REFERENCES courses(id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

After executing this code, I have an error:  Error 1005 (HY000)
Can't create table 'courses.lessons' (errno: 150)
What did I do wrong?

Comment: FOREIGN KEY(course) REFERENCES courses(id)- reference to a table which doesn't exist yet.USE \`courses\` with backticks.

Comment: The `courses` table is not yet created, and it's referenced in the `FOREIGN KEY` part of the lessons table. Try swapping the last two tables' order.

Comment: You cannot have a default on `TEXT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems. The first is trivial: you can't create a foreign key on `lessons.course` because the table does not exist yet, so the table creation fails. To fix that, move the `create table` for lessons after courses.

The second problem is that the column `lessons.teacher` does not have the same type as `teacher.id`. The foreign key can only be created when the columns have the same type, and you have defined `teacher.id` as `INT(10) UNSIGNED` while `lessons.teacher` is just `INT` (signed, and length 11 implied). Change the definition of the `lessons.teacher` column to that same type:

```
teacher INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
```